# How to import the data from .MYD to MATLAB?

Tags: mysql, matlab

I just obtained a bunch of MySQL data stored in raw MySQL ( MyISAM table) format in a `.MYD` file.

I now wish to start data analysis over those data. All I need to do is just reading the numbers into my MATLAB and process them.

What is the easiest way of doing so? I am using Mac OS, by the way.

Comment: Is it laads myd file?

Comment: @user1613360  I am sorry, what does that mean?

Answer (score 0):

1. Install MySQL (same version is preferable).
2. Go to the datadir (usually /var/lib/mysql)
3. Create directory "matlab" (or whatever)
4. Chown mysql:mysql if needed.
5. Put .MYD, .MYI and .frm files in the directory you just created. Chown if necessary.
6. Start MySQL.

Now you can export the data from mysql with mysqldump.

```
mysqldump -u [username] -p -t -T/path/to/directory [database] --fields-enclosed-by=\" --fields-terminated-by=,
```

will export in CSV format.